# Custom Polymer Element refresh data when visible?

Tags: polymer, web-component

In the element script I have:

```
Polymer({
    is: 'projects-page',
    attached: function () {
        this.async(function () {
            // access sibling or parent elements here
            var model = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/projects",
                headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken") }
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                model.projects = data;
                model.notifyPath('projects', model.projects);
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

            })
            .always(function () {

            });



        });
    }


});
```

I am needing to refresh this data when the route changes or when it becomes visible to the user.
I am still finding the Polymer docs lacking and any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
This is a partial answer.
[How can I refresh/reload Polymer element, when page changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482568/how-can-i-refresh-reload-polymer-element-when-page-changes)

Answer (score 1):

you could listen to the window url or any other variable that reflects the state of your application with a change-event listener and reload your ajax then. The `model` should be turned into a properity of your projects-page and the ajax-done event listener should use the Polymer-set function. So the view gets repopulated without any big hazzle.

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#change-callbacks

Comment: Interesting gonna run down this path a bit and see how maybe i can plumb the route Change event like this  through all the views maybe so when it changes it fires on the app then any thing that "registers" that property in the app would get a notify ..

Comment: What about when the view changes but the url don't change. E.g in a login page that the user is redirect to the content's page but the url stays the same.